# Is there a way to put these arrays in another array

Tags: python, arrays, loops

Looking to put filtered csv file names into a new array so can individually plot graphs with individual lines of best fit

Part of a project analysing data to determine a constant.

```
import scipy as sp

for f in A:
     with open(f,'r') as file:
         line1=file.readline()
         line1_split=line1.split(',')
         if 'Instrument Response: Good ' in line1_split[3]: #filters good from bad instrument response.
             print(f)
             print(line1_split[3])
             good_file_data=sp.array[f]
print(good_file_data[1])
```

Expected result is the 2nd file name which has good instrument response. 
Instead shows:

> "builtin method is not subscritable" error

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it now returns that when I write print(good_file_data[1]) that there are too many indices for array

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What were you hoping `sp.array[f]` (or the corrected `sp.array(f)`) to accomplish? Do you want to gather the file names into a list? `scipy` wouldn't really be needed for that. Just initialize an empty list and append to it in the body of the loop. Or -- initialize an empty `sp.array` and add to it. Whatever you use, you need to create a data structure to do so.

Comment: Thank you for the help, achieved what I wanted to

Answer (score 0):

since `sp.array` is a function/method, not a sequence object, using a subscription with square brackets will produce that error. Also,  `good_file_data` should be a sequence (list, array) to hold all table data reading from files from the collection A. Following is just a small change:

```
import scipy as sp

good_file_data = []
for f in A:
    with open(f, ‘r') as file:
        line1_split = file.readline().split(‘,’)
        if 'Instrument Response: Good ‘ in line1_split[3]:  # filters good from bad instrument response.
            print(f)
            print(line1_split[3])
            good_file_data.append(sp.array(f))
print(good_file_data[1])
```